# How do I print a booklet with double pages

Tags: pdf, printing

I tried to print [this](http://www.valvesoftware.com/company/Valve_Handbook_LowRes.pdf) booklet for a couple of minutes now, but I'm kinda stuck.

I already adjusted to print in duplex and left stapled (I know that's not right) but I can't figure out how to split these double pages to appear as a book.

Is there any way to achieve that?

**Edit:**

The core problem is that from page 2 on, all pages contain 2 physical pages.

Answer (score 1):

After you select Print, you'll get the print setup dialogue shown in the screenshot (I'm using Acrobat X). Yours may look a little different but you should see an option for "Booklet."

Select that option to bring up the related page-setup options. In the "BBoklet subset" drop-down menu, you'll want to choose "Both sides" if your printer is capable of duplexing (printing on both sides) on its own. If not, you'll want to select "Front side only," flip the pages over, then print "Back side only. It will alternate the pages as needed.

There are a lot of variables (e.g., the printer itself, page scaling/numbering/layout, paper size, etc.) that I cannot address so I recommend starting with just 4 B&W pages with minimal content until you get the hang of it.

[image]

Comment: I tried to narrow my problem by editing the question.

Comment: Do you mean you want to avoid scaling it down? Was the document created on 8.5 X 11 pages? It sounds like you need to change the page layout and orientation then reflow the text. That must be done in whichever word processor created the original (Acrobat/Reader won't do that).